# Odd Static Class Issue

Tags: c#, static, static-classes

Below is my very simple static class. Not sure what is wrong.
I am using it in a non static class that has a correct "using" statement. Intellisense sees the class and its one method.

I am getting the error

> The name 'SQLUserDataManager' does not
>   exist in the current context".

```
public static class SQLUserDataManager
    {
        public static SqlConnection connection;
        private static bool connectionMade;

        static SQLUserDataManager()
        {


        }

        public static void SpecifyConnection(string username, string password, string database)
        {

            string connectionString = "user id=" + username +
                                        ";password=" + password + ";server=127.0.0.1" +
                                        ";Trusted_Connection=yes" +
                                        ";database=NetunityUsers" +
                                        ";connection timeout=30";

        }
    }
```

Update:
This is the line I am using it in.

```
 SQLUserDataManager.SpecifyConnection("admin", "password", "Users");
```

**Problem Solved**

I have a DLL that includes the file that was having errors compiling. In this DLL I had yet to include my new file which contains this file. I included the file and all is good! ^_^

Comment: Your class definition looks fine. Can you show us how your using `SQLUserDataManager`?

Comment: All of the code above looks fine. It must be to do with your `using` statements in the code where you are using `SQLUserDataManager`.

Comment: The namespace the class is under is namespace Netunity.Utilities
I am doing 
using Netunity.Utilities; in the file I am trying to use it from.

Comment: In your example the SpecifyConnection method should return a string? Now the SpecifyConnection method is kinda useless.

Comment: Can you create a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem? Are you sure you've got the right using directive *in the file which contains that line*?

Comment: Odd it works in my Main.cs file but not my the file I need it in. xD

Comment: SpecifyConnection is not finished yet. :)

Comment: @bobber205: Do you have the using directive in that file? You can't just put it in one place - it needs to be in every file using that namespace.

Comment: Problem solved. Had to do with a DLL project included in the solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the error occur ?
Is the SQLUserDataManager class in another namespace then the class where you refer to SQLUserDataManager ?

Comment: The error occurs in a ctor for another class that is not static.
I have pasted the relevent line in my OP.

Answer (score 0):

The staticness and non-staticness are almost certainly irrelevant - although it would help if you could show us how you're trying to use it.

Is this in ASP.NET, by any chance? I wonder whether it's to do with the way that ASP.NET ends up being built, and what code lives where. Could you give us more details?

Comment: It is not ASP.NET.
Just a regular C# project.

Comment: Okay, that's very odd then. And you see it in intellisense, but then compilation fails? And this is within the same project?